# Export Each Access Table To Individual Workbook

Tags: vba, ms-access, export-to-excel, ms-access-2013

I have been using this syntax which will export every table in a database to ONE excel workbook, but now my needs are to export every table to it's own workbook.  How could this be tweaked to export each table to it's own workbook?

```
Sub ExportToExcel()
  Dim td As DAO.TableDef, db As DAO.Database
  Dim out_file As String

  out_file = "C:\fromaccess.xlsx"

  Set db = CurrentDb()
    For Each td in db.TableDefs
      If Left(td.Name, 4) = "MSys" Then
        'Do Nothing
      Else
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, td.Name, out_file, True, Replace(td.Name, "dbo_","")
      End If
      Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
I tried the suggestion by @HA560 but get an error of

> Run-time error '91':
>   Object variable or With block variable not set

This is updated code:

```
Sub ExportToExcel()
Dim td As DAO.TableDef, db As DAO.Database
Dim out_file As String
Dim xl As Excel.Application

out_file = "C:\fromaccess.xlsx"

Set db = CurrentDb()
For Each td in db.TableDefs
xl.Workbooks.Add  
If Left(td.Name, 4) = "MSys" Then
    'Do Nothing
  Else
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, td.Name, out_file, True, Replace(td.Name, "dbo_","")
  End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: After for each use `workbooks.add()`method...`out_file=activeworkbook.path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a long one which includes a three procedures.  After running you should have a list of table names and TRUE/FALSE in the immediate window saying whether the export was successful.

`ExportAll` - The main procedure.
`CreateXL` - this creates an instance of Excel.  It uses late binding, so no need to set references.

`QueryExportToXL` - this is the code to export the table.  I haven't used `TransferSpreadsheet` as I like more control.

- You need to pass a worksheet reference to the function.
- You can pass either a query name or a recordset to the function.
- You can pass an alternative sheet name.
- The default cell to paste into is A1, but you can change this.
- By default it adjusts the column widths to fit.
- You can pass a collection of heading names to use instead of the field names.

There's not much error handling in there - such as passing a different number of heading names than there are fields, giving illegal sheet names.
It needs work :)

```
Public Sub ExportAll()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim oXL As Object
    Dim oWrkBk As Object

    Set db = CurrentDb

    'Create instance of Excel.
    Set oXL = CreateXL

    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then

            'Create workbook with single sheet.
            Set oWrkBk = oXL.WorkBooks.Add(-4167) 'xlWBATWorksheet

            'Open the table recordset.
            Set rst = tdf.OpenRecordset

            'In the immediate window display table name and TRUE/FALSE if exported successfully.
            Debug.Print tdf.Name & " - " & QueryExportToXL(oWrkBk.worksheets(1), , rst, tdf.Name)

            'Save and close the workbook.
            oWrkBk.SaveAs "<path to folder>" & tdf.Name
            oWrkBk.Close

        End If
    Next tdf

End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : CreateXL
' Author    : Darren Bartrup-Cook
' Date      : 02/10/2014
' Purpose   : Creates an instance of Excel and passes the reference back.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function CreateXL(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpXL As Object

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case Excel is not running. '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of Excel. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                            '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    oTmpXL.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreateXL = oTmpXL

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateXL."
            Err.Clear
    End Select


End Function


'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : QueryExportToXL
' Author    : Darren Bartrup-Cook
' Date      : 26/08/2014
' Purpose   : Exports a named query or recordset to Excel.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function QueryExportToXL(wrkSht As Object, Optional sQueryName As String, _
                                                  Optional rst As DAO.Recordset, _
                                                  Optional SheetName As String, _
                                                  Optional rStartCell As Object, _
                                                  Optional AutoFitCols As Boolean = True, _
                                                  Optional colHeadings As Collection) As Boolean

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim oXLCell As Object
    Dim vHeading As Variant

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    If sQueryName <> "" And rst Is Nothing Then

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Open the query recordset.                               '
        'Any parameters in the query need to be evaluated first. '
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(sQueryName)
        For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
            prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
        Next prm
        Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
    End If

    If rStartCell Is Nothing Then
        Set rStartCell = wrkSht.cells(1, 1)
    Else
        If rStartCell.Parent.Name <> wrkSht.Name Then
            Err.Raise 4000, , "Incorrect Start Cell parent."
        End If
    End If


    If Not rst.BOF And Not rst.EOF Then
        With wrkSht
            Set oXLCell = rStartCell

            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            'Paste the field names from the query into row 1 of the sheet. '
            'Or the alternative field names provided in a collection.      '
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            If colHeadings Is Nothing Then
                For Each fld In rst.Fields
                    oXLCell.Value = fld.Name
                    Set oXLCell = oXLCell.Offset(, 1)
                Next fld
            Else
                For Each vHeading In colHeadings
                    oXLCell.Value = vHeading
                    Set oXLCell = oXLCell.Offset(, 1)
                Next vHeading
            End If

            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            'Paste the records from the query into row 2 of the sheet. '
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Set oXLCell = rStartCell.Offset(1, 0)
            oXLCell.copyfromrecordset rst
            If AutoFitCols Then
                .Columns.Autofit
            End If

            If SheetName <> "" Then
                .Name = SheetName
            End If

            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            'TO DO: Has recordset imported correctly? '
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            QueryExportToXL = True

        End With
    Else

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'There are no records to export, so the export has failed. '
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        QueryExportToXL = False
    End If

    Set db = Nothing

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure QueryExportToXL."
            Err.Clear
            Resume
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: --> What version of Excel does this work with?  I have tried to use it with Excel 2013, but keep getting an error of Error -2147467262' (No such interface supported0 in procedure QueryExportToXL)

Comment: It's for use in Access.

Comment: Yes, I understand it works within Access, but is it limited to which versions of Excel it can export to?  Was not sure why I keep getting the error.

Comment: Ah ok, it's worked in 2003 and 2010.  Afraid I haven't been able to try in any other versions though.  Which line does it error on?

Comment: In the QueryExportToXL procedure this line oXLCell.copyfromrecordset rst

Comment: Not sure then - CopyFromRecordset should work in 2013 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx).  Hopefully someone else has an idea?

Comment: The strange part is it copies headers no problem, but when it tries to copy the actual data the error is thrown

Answer (score -1):

After for each use `workbooks.add()`method...`out_file=activeworkbook.path`

Comment: I also get an error, any further insight you care to provide?

Comment: @user2676140 pls follow above mentioned code by darren

Comment: Very nice Darren!!